# Getting started with Azure Machine Learning

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am new to Azure ML and Machine Learning in its entirety, I would like to create an application that matches resumes to job requests / postings on job portals. I need advice on where can I find info with this regard, I've read a bit about clustering algorithms, K-mean ,etc but I could not clearly get a grasp of it.Are there any detailed tutorials on how approach the design such an application?

Comment: Tutorial recommendation questions are off-topic for StackOverflow. And... a simple google search of 'Azure Machine Learning' will link you right to the Azure site itself with plenty of getting-started info.

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario I think recommender system will work well. Refer the following MVA tutorial and you'll get an idea.

https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/building-recommendation-systems-in-azure-13765?l=9jtc5olXB_205513172